# How does Zipkin generate and store the 16 char trace id used in the get Api of /traces/{traceId}

Tags: zipkin, distributed-tracing

I am using Zipkin for distributed tracing. I have added zipkin-storage-mysql dependency in order to save the traces in MySQL DB. When I query ZIPKIN_SPANS table, I don't find the 16 char trace id in TRACE_ID Colum that I use in order to load the trace on zipkin UI.

for ex: `localhost:9411/traces/4bcdd0bd5d2f70c0`

Please help me understand how can I figure it out. Also, How can I add a new column to the table for associating an application-specific id with it

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 entries in mysql zipkin_spans table

1. **trace_id_high** -> corresponds to decimal representation of first 16 hex character
2. **id** -> corresponds to decimal representation of lower 16 hex character

**Example**

32 character hex trace id **5ec92d0240cd9dee0421f4763e9f674f** displayed in zipkin ui corresponds to

**trace_id_high = 6830039797584469486 in mysql** (5EC92D0240CD9DEE -> upper 16 hex character)

**id = 297787839077115727 in mysql** (421F4763E9F674F -> lower 16 hex charecter)